# How to produce a query that will bring up a list of employees who do not have specific training.

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been working on a Database for quite some time now which records and keeps track of training due across our group of companies. I am at a stage where I am happy with it and would say its near enough complete in terms and making it.

I have several queries which produces reports showing only most recent training records per course per employee, due training and all employees with certain types of training, however I can not find out how to produce a query which shows up employees who do not have a certain type of training.

The tables which i would be using for this are Employee Information, Training Records, Course ID :

**Employee Information Table:**

> Emp ID | First Name | Surname | etc..

**Training Record Table:**

> Record ID | Emp ID | Course ID | etc..

**Course ID Table**

> Course ID | Course Name

So each Employee can have a number of training records for all different types of courses and  and can have multiple records for the same course.

I was wondering how can you make a query which will show all employees who do not have a certain type of training either because they have never done the course or because it is out of date. I have a query which only brings the most current of each training record up so I'm guessing i would use that query to help.

If someone could shed some light on this problem it would be great, Ive been trying for weeks now and still haven't got any where.

Many Thanks

Clare

Answer (score 0):

You mey use **EXIST** keyword

```
Select EMP.* from Employee EMP
Where NOT EXIST
(
   Select TR.Emp_ID from Training_Record TR where 
   TR.Emp_ID = EMP.Emp_ID
   -- AND TR. Course_ID = (some data)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have it, make a query from the training table with the selected course and current dates.  Then you can use an outer join between the employee table and this query to create another query including all employees and any matching records from  the training records query, then select for null in any field from the training table.  This will list all employees that do not have the specified training.